# Is there a problem if the val_loss increases suddenly at specific epoch then decreases?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am trying to train CNN model on more over 6000, 224 x 224 color images, I split them to 4500 images for training, 1000 for validation and 1000 images for testing.

I am using this function to build my model:

```
def model_build (layer, augmentation = False, dropout_value= 0., input_shape = (224,224,3)):

  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1./255))
  if augmantentation:
    model.add(data_augmentation)
  
  for num_filter, size_filter, padding in layer:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= num_filter, kernel_size= size_filter, activation= 'relu', padding = padding))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= num_filter, kernel_size= size_filter, activation= 'relu', padding = padding))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_value))
    
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_value))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = 'softmax'))

  return model

layer = [(32,3, 'valid'),(64,5, 'valid'), (128,5, 'valid'),(128,7, 'valid')]
model_aug2 = model_build(layer, augmentation = True, dropout_value= 0.6)
```

please notice that I'm using augmentation.
and for training:

```
callback=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", patience=5, mode="min", 
restore_best_weights=True)
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model_aug2.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model_aug2.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_valid,y_valid), epochs=100, callbacks = [callback])
```

I plot val_loss and loss curves:
[val_loss and train_loss curves with augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqe10.png)

[val_loss and train_loss curves without augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05wGf.png)

I am not sure what this increase means, I will also attach a picture showing the curves before adding the augmentation, as the curve was unstable but gave better results, can someone explain to me the behavior of these curves and what they mean please.

Comment: I do not see if this is a problem. You model learns "something" as the cost is decreasing. The difference between two plots is that with augmentation your model in not overfitting, whereas without augmentation, it overfits after certain epochs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that training a DNN is an art, both from the efficiency POV and from the optimization POV.

That peak might be caused by many things, for example:

- you are using Adam optimizer, which has momentum, and maybe that lead you to a higher loss region (think it like you throwing a ball down to a mountain in a valley between two mountains, the ball will go down, but then it will, due to momentum, go uphill to the other mountain)
- your optimizer is stochastic, and instead of calculating the actual gradient, it tries to estimate it... that estimation, mainly in the literature, works under many conditions, one of them is usually bounded variance (your gradient is well defined and it's estimation can be performed on a minibatch)... with data augmentation, maybe a minibatch is not representative of your dataset, therefore the optimizer will do a step in the wrong "direction"
- you might be seeing a possible "exploding gradient" due to a cliff in the loss function, due to a stepsize that is too big, and not using the clip gradient property of your optimizer:
  [image]

Those are possible reasons, but none of them have to be considered an issue of the model, they are just part of the process, they might happen or not, and you can tackle them or not, depending if they are actually causing problems or not